# Simplify matrix product with inverse term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have the following matrix product:
$$C=X(X^TAX)^{-1}X^T$$
where $A$ is an $m\ x\ m$ sparse symmetric positive definite matrix and $X$ is a sparse rectangular $m\ x\ n$ matrix. In case it matters, $X$ is the nullspace of another matrix used to constrain the solutions. Everything is real-valued. $X$ has the property that $X^TX=I_n$.

**Because my matrices have so many seemingly beneficial properties, is there any matrix manipulation that can simplify this expression?** I was hopeful that some of the $X$ terms could be eliminated or removed from the inverse term, but this does not appear to be the case.
Typically, I do not need to explicitly form this product and can treat it as an operator on some vector $f$
$$r=X(X^TAX)^{-1}X^Tf$$
My usual procedure is:

1. $g=X^Tf$
2. Form $X^TAX$ explicitly using MKL's `mkl_sparse_sypr` [routine](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/inspector-executor-sparse-blas-routines/inspector-executor-sparse-blas-execution-routines/mkl-sparse-sypr.html). Forming this matrix product is so much faster than performing 3 matrix-vector products in an iterative solver routine. I have no idea how it achieves this performance, but it is faster than any of my "clever" solutions.
3. Use conjugate gradient (CG) to compute $z=(X^TAX)^{-1}g$. I have a preconditioned CG loop that uses all MKL sparse BLAS routines.
4. $r=Xz$

For linear algebra, I am using C++ and am reasonably adept with Eigen (whenever possible), SuiteSparse (mostly for their sparse QR and rectangular LU decompositions), and Intel MKL (for my CG loop).

Edit: narrowed the question to focus on my primary concern

Comment: We can only have $XX^T = I_m$ **and** $X^TX = I_n$ if $m = n$, so something about your question is off

Comment: I guess its just X^T X = I_n, which is guaranteed by the QR decomposition that yielded X There are some off-diagonal coefficients in X X^T that were small, so I wanted to believe it was something special.

Comment: Keep in mind that the rank of $XX^T$ is at most $n$, which guarantees that it is at least a certain non-zero distance away from the identity matrix